# First ionization energy of hydrogen molecule

Tags: bond, molecules, atoms, electrons, energy

If we have the dissociation's energies of hydrogen molecule $\ce{H_{2}}$($D_{0}$) and the corresponding molecule ion $\ce{H_{2}^{+}}$ ($D_{1}$) together with the first energy of ionization of hydrogen atom ($E_{I}$), how can we estimate the first energy of ionization of hydrogen molecule?